# is MFC application using UTF-16 for CString when UNICODE is defined

Tags: unicode, mfc, c-strings

I know CString use WCHAR if we define UNICODE.
However, is it UTF-16 encoded?
Is there an official reference?
I'm trying to find the unicode codepoint value of a character in the CString.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's UTF-16 encoded, because Windows itself is based on UTF-16. I'm not sure if there's any documentation that would state it explicitly.

Note that for any codepoints above 0xffff, in particular emoticons, a codepoint will require two characters within the CString. This is known as a surrogate pair.

Comment: Explicitly here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson thanks for the link, that goes into some detail about what Windows uses. My comment was more about `CString` specifically.